# incrementing/updating a value in a row in MySQl Table

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to make it so that I can update a value in my MySQL database value. now say a user named "admin" logs in. I want to make a query so that the value of the cell in the blankets column increases by the integer input by the user next to the name. What is the query I need to use so that my code looks at what user is signed into the and then it updates the value depending on what that user input? say the user input 2. so I want the blankets column to increment by 2. if I'm unclear somewhere please let me know. if I'm being repetitive ignore I'm still learning [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79jl4.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] -- there are plenty of tutorials out there on how to deal with databases as a beginner. This is not a code writing service but a community to solve problems with code. You can [edit] your question at any time to include relevant code you're having issues with, but please don't expect elaborate beginner courses here. Thanks!

Comment: Do you already know how to write an update query in a SQL client? Do you know how to use where conditions? Do you know how to use JDBC in general? Where does your input come from? What code did you write so far? As you can see there are a lot of questions so we can't help specifically since we don't even know the level of knowledge you're starting with. If that level is very low we can't just explain everything here as Alexander already stated. In that case you might want to grab a tutorial and work through it step by step.

Comment: yea i knew i would have been a bit clear. So i have worked with insertion and retrieval but only at a basic level. I have everything setup. JDBC, my application, and a MySQL server and also a table. my level is quite low, im just a beginner, but in simple i want to update a INT value in a table by a number that the user enters in Jtextfield. How will i write a query for that. you dont need to explain me everything just explain to me what query will be used